# Non-Authenticated FreeMarker page in alfresco share

Tags: customization, alfresco, alfresco-share

i have create a new page in alfresco share but the page cannot be displayed without login! how can i make this page enabled without login.

my file in "/alfresco/templates/blog/demo/custom-viewer.ftl".

and this file contains "custom-viewer.ftl":

```
<#include "include/alfresco-template.ftl" />
<@templateHeader>
   <@script type="text/javascript" src="${url.context}/res/modules/documentlibrary/doclib-actions.js" group="document-details"/>
   <@link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${url.context}/res/components/document-    details/document-details-panel.css" group="document-details"/>
   <@templateHtmlEditorAssets />
</@>

<@templateBody>
   <@region id="web-preview" scope="template"/>
</@>

<@templateFooter>

</@>
```

and the file in "/alfresco/site-data/pages/custom-viewer.xml".

and this file contains "custom-viewer.xml":

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<page>
   <title>Custom Viewer</title>
   <template-instance>custom-viewer</template-instance>
   <authentication>none</authentication>
</page>
```

the page is work correctly but i need it to work without login? any help please?!!

Comment: is your page working or displayed once you login to alfresco?

Comment: yes it's work correctly and displayed in this alfresco share URL path `http://localhost:8080/share/page/custom-viewer?nodeRef=workspace://SpacesStore/somecontentId`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is probably not your page which needs login but the components it's including.
I'm seeing component regioun web-preview, if this defaults to the default web-preview: **site-webscripts\org\alfresco\components\preview\web-preview.get.desc.xml**

Then this components needs authentication, there is no `<authentication>` tag, so it defaults to user.

If you delete that **<@region....>** tag, you'll see the page.

Comment: i change the default web-preview for "web-preview.get.desc.xml" to none but no luck and still not work except when i login to alfresco or you mean i have to create a new custom component and new javascript?

Comment: Hi, yep if you remove the web-preview and first check if you get to a blank page. You can even set a <div>Hello World</div> in the .ftl.