# Alfresco Share document library without login

Tags: javascript, authentication, alfresco, alfresco-share

I need to allow  guest users  to access the document library of the Alfresco Share.

I created a template similar to documentlibrary, where I set the authentication level required to guest:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<page>
   <title>Document Library</title>
   <title-id>page.arquivos.title</title-id>
   <description>Document library withot</description>
   <description-id>page.arquivos.description</description-id>
   <template-instance>arquivos</template-instance>
   <authentication>guest</authentication>
</page>
```

But the javascript componet called by template not work if a non-authentication user access the page.

In this case the page shows the message "Loading the Document Library" while reloading the page over and over again.

I tried to put a *runas="user"* in the xml, but it does not work for this case.

```
<authentication runas="user">guest</authentication>
```

I am looking for a way to log into an consumer account via javascript code, to resolve the dependence of the component by a authenticated user.

Any help or suggestion is appreciated.

This case is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18683087/non-authenticated-freemarker-page-in-alfresco-share) and [that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13363398/alfresco-share-sites-dashlet-for-document-library)

Sometimes, the following error is displayed:

> **An error has occured in the Share component: /share/service/components/documentlibrary/documentlist_v2.
>   It responded with a status of 500 - Internal Error.**
>   **Error Code Information:** 500 - An error inside the HTTP server which prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>   **Error Message:** 09160143 Failed to execute script 'classpath*:alfresco/site-webscripts/org/alfresco/components/documentlibrary/documentlist-v2.get.js': 09160142 09160143 Failed during processing of Google Docs subsystem status configuration from **Alfresco:** 09160142 Unable to retrieve Google Docs subsystem status from Alfresco: 401
>   **Server:** Alfresco Spring WebScripts - v1.2.0 (Release 1308) schema 1.000
>   **Time:** 16/10/2013 08:02:13
>   Click here to view full technical information on the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<authentication>none</authentication>
```

And maybe even with:

```
<transaction>none</transaction>
```

Comment: The same problem persists.
I can access the template without login, but the component does not work.
I updated the scope with the error message that appears...

Comment: What you're forgetting is that you need to do this at all the webscripts which are fired from the document library template, this means all the /slingshot/{site}/children like of webscripts and other which are triggered in the page.

Comment: Not sure if I made this modification in right place.
I changed the following files:
classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/doclist.get.desc.xml
classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/doclist.get.desc.xml

The problem with the User unauthenticated continues, but in addition  no item is displayed to authenticated.

Comment: classes/alfresco/templates/webscripts/org/alfresco/slingshot/documentlibrary-v2/‌​node.get.desc.xml