# guest user Alfresco / access without login

Tags: authentication, alfresco, alfresco-share

How do I create a guest user in my alfresco, or waive some parts of the website so they can be accessed by the public, without being required a login?

version 4.2.d

Answer (score 3):

You have to implement a Web Script with:

- the authentication setting to guest
- put all your public contents inside the **Guest Home** space
- use the SearchService of Alfresco and search contents inside the Guest Home
- When you invoke the HTTP call to the Web Script put the parameter
  guest=true in the querystring: **/alfresco/service/yourCompany/yourService?guest=true**

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

you should probably write some web scripts with guest authentication in your descriptor file,
here is some documentation on how to achieve that:
[Web scripts examples](http://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Web_Scripts_Examples)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is not an easy way to solve this.

I have done some unsuccessfully tests with webscript...

My next effort consists of add a extra authentication method like the ldap or pass-through.

- and do the login in a specific user by script(PHP or Javascript)

or

- to configure the properties of the pass-through that map the unknow user to guest. [ntlm.authentication.mapUnknownUserToGuest](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.alfresco.enterprise.doc%2Ftasks%2Fauth-alfrescoexternal-sso.html)

I also appreciate a solution for this issue. Heres my question of some days ago.
[Alfresco Share document library without login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19382279/alfresco-share-document-library-without-login)